# "Говорит [что] любит" - нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Возьмём фразу

> Он говорит, что любит.

Здесь косвенная речь, но как поступить, если опустить "что", нужно ли ставить какой-то знак препинания в фразах на месте вопросительного знака, и если нужно - то какой?

- Говорит (?) любит.
- Говорит (?) да.
- Говорит (?) чай. *(его спросили, что он будет, чай или кофе)*

Comment: please, can you be more precise what exactly you are asking, what's you assumptions on what is the correct answer etc - now it's just not clear.

Comment: к тому же вы русскоязычный - тогда надо ещё чётче формулировать )))

Comment: @shabunc вот,  отредактировал) посмотрите,  пожалуйста

Comment: @khimick - спасибо. Поглядите пожалуйста, я отредактировал ещё - вот, чтобы у вас было представление, что делает вопрос более ясным. В том числе и вёрстка ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут **нужна запятая**. Вы правильно заметили, "что" попросту пропущено (как и "он"), но это не отменяет того факта, что предложение это - сложноподчинённое и обособляется запятой.

Но правила также **допускают и** интонационное **тире**.
В справочнике Розенталя читаем:

> Тире ставится для интонационного отделения главной части
> сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной. Чаще всего тире
> употребляется в тех случаях, когда главной части предшествует.

И это на самом деле очень неплохой критерий, можно ли тут поставить тире.
Вот посмотрите, в приведённый вами примерах части можно переставить местами:

- Чай — говорит.
- Любит — говорит.

Немножко нам неудачный пример достался, потому что со словом "говорит" кажется, что это вообще прямая речь, которую надо обособлять иначе, но идея такая: если можно переставить местами, то можно и обособить интонационно дефисом.

Но в целом дефис будет предпочтительней только если сложное предложение содержит ещё какую-то часть, например:

> Говорит — любит, а сам на других заглядывается!

Наконец, знак препинания **может быть опущен**, если нужно передать стремительность живой, разговорной речи, например:

> *Она:* Вась, ну любишь меня, любишь?
>
> *Он:* Говорю люблю, отстань наконец!

Comment: благодарю за ответ! То,  что надо!

Comment: @khirnick , не думаю, что ответ правилен в части "знак препинания может быть опущен, если нужно передать стремительность живой, разговорной речи". Пример "Говорю люблю, отстань наконец!", уверен, неправилен. Можно бы было написать "говорю, люблю" или как прямую речь "говорю: 'Люблю', отстань наконец". Но не просто "говорю люблю". Не могу ничем подтвердить, это просто моя интуиция, но уверен, что это ошибка

Comment: не говоря о том, что фраза "знак препинания может быть опущен, если нужно передать стремительность живой, разговорной речи" сама по себе кажется ошибочной. Знаки препинания в русском языке существуют не для отметки пауз в "не живой, не разговорной речи", а для разделения смысловых частей предложения. И поэтому навряд ли кто-то где-то в каком-то учебнике написал бы такое, что "можно опускать", чтоб передать "живость"

Comment: @user907860  - есть такое понятие как авторская пунктуация - дело в том, что живой язык не всегда подчиняется правилам, предусмотренным учебником. Кстати, пунктуация существует и для интонационного разделения - для тех самых пауз.

Comment: @khirnick , я согласен, не все подчиняется правилам, 20% людей, по моим прикидкам, вообще не могут написать диктант по русскому, т.е. они "не подчиняются правилам" . Но вопрос-то именно про официально установленные правила (пусть автор вопроса меня поправит, если я не прав) т.е. правила государственные (от минобразования там и т.п.), академические и т.п. Естественно, что  цель ведь не в правилах, а в том, чтоб тебя поняли, но тогда это ответ еще более неправильный, т.к. он говорит, что "запятая нужна", а должно быть "пишите как хотите, все нормально"